# two integrations with functions inside

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

I have thee next problem

> If f is a continuous function that satisfies $$\int_3^4 f(t)\,dt=3$$
> calculate $$\int_9^{16}\frac{f(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx$$

I don't even know how to start, does it talk about the first function being applied in the nominator of the second? so $3 =\sqrt x$?

Comment: $u=\sqrt x$ ...

Comment: Care to explain what has this to do with `complex-analysis`? Or with `sequences-and-series`? Or `functional-analysis`?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos A function is being analyzed, and it looks pretty complicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $$
\sqrt{x}=t,x=t^2
$$
And we get
$$
\int_9^{16}{\frac{f\left( \sqrt{x} \right)}{\sqrt{x}}dx}=\int_3^4{\frac{f\left( t \right)}{t}2tdt}=2\int_3^4{f\left( t \right) dt}=6
$$